# Negative margin behaving different in Chrome and FF

Tags: html, css

I have a problem:

`wrapper3` class has `100% height`, and  `footer` is a sibling, `min-height` is 15 for footer, and has a `8px padding` `(Total height 31px)`. So I put `margin-bottom: -31px` to allow footer in the same page.

In FF it works good, there is no `Y-scollbar`, but in Chrome, `wrapper3 fills 100%` of the screen, and its not allowing footer to get on top of it. However, if I put `margin-bottom: -62`, it works as expected (Obviously not in FF). So, in the ultimate case, how can I specify -62 for Chrome only?

See: http://tracker.fusiondev.com.ar

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `margin-bottom` for Chrome only, try `overflow:hidden` and `height:100%` (as apposed to `min-height`) for class `wrapper`, it won't override your footer div and will give you a cross browser compatible solution.

Comment: Well this didn't work but I've set overflow: hidden in wrapper, and overflow: auto in wrapper2, and giving wrapper2 a height of 1px and min-height: 100% worked good, at least in first look. Seems that the problem is somewhere in Chrome with min-height: 100% and negative margins, because in FF it looks good.

Comment: Change `wrapper` class to `height:100%`, not `min-height:100%`